# I am getting the output in Big Endian Format

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num, i = 0,pos;
    printf(" Enter num \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for( i = 0; i < 31; i++ )
    {   
        pos = 1 << i;

        if ( num & pos )
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");

    }   
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

/*
O/P
Enter Num
12
0011000000000000

*/
```

But i want to print the o/p as 0000000000001100
So, What are the changes i have to made to get the desired o/p

Comment: By any chance were you just messing around with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597940/how-to-insert-zeros-between-bits-in-a-bitmap  - that's why I had a replacement `for` loop just lying around...

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the least significant bit first.  Change your for loop to count down:

```
      for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:
Seem that I'm the one who overlooked desired output. So the solutions provided by others will work for the OP.**

---

I'm surprised people overlooked the fact that endianness usually applies to byte level instead of bit, which make the plain index-based loop fail to provide required output.

for a decimal to big-endian byte, you need :

```
while (num)
{
    big <<= 8;
    big |= num & 0xFF;
    num >>= 8;
}
```

so in order to output little-endian integer into big-endian binaries, you need :

```
// 'num' was 4-byte (int) data in little-endian format
while (num)
{
    // select required byte block
    unsigned char curByte = num & 0xFF;

    // prints the byte binaries
    for(int iBit=7; iBit>=0; --iBit)
    {
        unsigned char theBit = curByte >> iBit;
        if (theBit & 0x1)
            putchar('1');
        else
            putchar('0');

    }

    // shifts to next byte block
    num >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP simply wanted the binary representation of the int printed out in with most-significant bit on the left and least-significant on the left. Look at his example at the end of his question.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `for` loop to be more like:

```
#define BIT(x) (1U << (x))

for (i = 31; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (x & BIT(i)) {
        putchar('1');
    }
    else {
        putchar('0');
    }

}
```

Comment: @YeenFei: I don't think the question was talking about byte-order endianness - just the bit order of his printout of the bits in an `int`.