# Convert byte to specific mask with bit hack

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

I have number with binary representation `0000abcd`.

How convert it to `0a0b0c0d` with smallest number of operations?
How convert `0a0b0c0d` back to `0000abcd`?

I was searching for a solution here:
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html and other

**Generally the problem a bit more than described.**

Given first number `a₁b₁c₁d₁a₂b₂c₂d₂` and second number `a₃a₄b₃b₄c₃c₄d₃d₄`

If (`a₁` and `a₂` = `0`) then clear both `a₃` and `a₄`, if (`a₃` and `a₄` = `0`) then clear both `a₁` and `a₂`, etc.

My solution:

```
    a₁b₁c₁d₁a₂b₂c₂d₂
OR  0 0 0 0 a₁b₁c₁d₁ ( a₁b₁c₁d₁a₂b₂c₂d₂ >> 4)
    ----------------
    0 0 0 0 a b c d
? (magic transformation)
    ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
    ----------------
    0 a 0 b 0 c 0 d
OR  a 0 b 0 c 0 d 0  (0 a 0 b 0 c 0 d << 1)
    ----------------
    a a b b c c d d
AND a₃a₄b₃b₄c₃c₄d₃d₄
    ----------------
    A₃A₄B₃B₄C₃C₄D₃D₄ (clear bits)
```

**UPDATED:** (thanks for @AShelly)

```
x = a₁b₁c₁d₁a₂b₂c₂d₂
x = (x | x >> 4) & 0x0F
x = (x | x << 2) & 0x33
x = (x | x << 1) & 0x55
x = (x | x << 1)

y = a₃a₄b₃b₄c₃c₄d₃d₄
y = (y | y >> 1) & 0x55
y = (y | y >> 1) & 0x33
y = (y | y >> 2) & 0x0F
y = (y | y << 4)
```

work for 32-bit with constants `0x0F0F0F0F`, `0x33333333`, `0x55555555` (and twice long for 64-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have number with binary
>   representation 0000abcd. How convert
>   it to 0a0b0c0d with smallest number of
>   operations?

Isn't this exactly "[Interleave bits of X and Y"](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#Interleave64bitOps) where Y is 0?  Bit Twiddling Hacks has [Multiple Solutions](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN) that don't use a lookup table.

> How convert 0a0b0c0d back to 0000abcd?

See "[How to de-interleave bits (UnMortonizing?)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137266/how-to-de-interleave-bits-unmortonizing)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the smallest number of operations, use a look-up table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one go, you should shift bits on per bit basis:

Pseudo code:

```
    X1 = a₁b₁c₁d₁
    X2 = a₂b₂c₂d₂
    Bm = 1 0 0 0 // Bit mask

    Result = 0;

    while (/* some bytes left */)
    {
       Result += (X1 and Bm) << 1 or (X2 and Bm);
       Bm = Bm shr 1
       Result = Result shl 2;
    }
```

As a result you will get a1a2b1b2c1c2d1d2

Comment: Too many ops. I look at this solution, but without brunches: if (a₁b₁c₁d₁a₂b₂c₂d₂ & 10001000 == 0) a₃a₄b₃b₄c₃c₄d₃d₄ &= 00111111

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible (without lookup table) to do it in less operations using binary arithmetic and x86 or x64 processor architecture. Correct me if I'm mistaken but your problem is about moving bits. Having the `abcd` bits you want to get `0a0b0c0d` bits in one operation. The problem starts when you will look at how many bits the 'a','b','c' and 'd' has to travel.

```
'a' was 4-th, became 7-th, distance travelled 3 bits
'b' was 3-rd, became 5-th, distance travelled 2 bits
'c' was 2-nd, became 3-rd, distance travelled 1 bit
'd' was 1-st, became 1-st, distance travelled 0 bits
```

There is no such processor instruction that will move these bits dynamically to a different distance. Though if you have different input representations of the same number for free, for example you have precomputed several values which you are using in a cycle, than maybe it will be possible to gain some optimization, this is the effect you get when using additional knowledge about the topology. You just have to choose whether it will be:

```
[4 cycles, n^0 memory]
[2 cycles, n^1 memory]
[1 cycle , n^2 memory]
```

Comment: Maybe my mistake in explanation, of course it's not a single operation and I understand that bits shifted to different distance.
But lookup table like "easy way" - you can solve, but don't understand the nature of numbers.