# How I can remove all odds bits in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have int 136970250 (1000 0010 1010 0000 0000 0000 1010) ->
I need to remove all odd bits(1, 3, 5, 7...)

1000 0010 1010 0000 0000 0000 1010 -> 10 0111 0000 0011 (9987) - because this bits do not have information.

How to do it?

Comment: Show your tries and where exactly have you problem

Comment: Should be & with all even bits

Comment: So not only mask out the bits, but actually shorten the number of bits? What is the actual problem you want to solve? Why do you want to do this (actually remove bits, moving them around to fit a smaller data type)? What is the use-case?

Comment: I'd call that removing the even bits, but that probably depends on whether you start counting at 1 or 0.

Comment: Why not create a mask of `0xAA` for *each byte* (e.g. `0xAAAAAAAA` for 32-bit number) and then **AND** with your original number? (or if it is actually *even* bits you want, then use `0x55` for each byte)

Comment: @TripeHound excellent point, I was just addressing masking and zeroing all odd/even bits, but not the removal. (If they don't have data, why go to the trouble to remove the bits? Not up to me to say, but it seems like you could check that *zero is zero* without removing bits?)

Comment: How is this "too broad"? It's an extremely specific question.

Comment: Related: [How can I shuffle bits efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25750844/1187415) and [How to efficiently de-interleave bits (inverse Morton)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4909263/1187415)

Comment: @harold: "Too broad" is a close reason for questions which are merely requirements, without showing any effort: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270903/1187415.

Answer (score 5):

> How I can remove all odds bits...?
>   I need to remove all odd bits(1, 3, 5, 7...)

OP's single example looks like retaining the odd bits, given that the least significant bit is usually bit 0.

This answers assumes code needs to *retain* the even bits and discard the odd  ones.  It is easy to adjust the algorithm to retain  other bits.

---

Rather than a loop of 32 iterations, **shift bits in groups**.  First pair-up required bits, then in groups of 4, then in groups of 8, etc.

Say we want to retain bits `0b .a.b .c.d .e.f .g.h .i.j .k.l .m.n .o.p`

```
uint16_t IK_RemoveOddBits(uint32_t x) {
  // x = 0b .a.b .c.d .e.f .g.h .i.j .k.l .m.n .o.p

  x = ((x & 0x44444444) >> 1) | ((x & 0x11111111) >> 0);
  // x = 0b ..ab ..cd ..ef ..gh ..ij ..kl ..mn ..op

  x = ((x & 0x30303030) >> 2) | ((x & 0x03030303) >> 0);
  // x = 0b .... abcd .... efgh .... ijkl .... mnop

  x = ((x & 0x0F000F00) >> 4) | ((x & 0x000F000F) >> 0);
  // x = 0b .... .... abcd efgh .... .... ijkl mnop

  x = ((x & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | ((x & 0x000000FF) >> 0);
  // x = 0b .... .... .... .... abcd efgh ijkl mnop

  return x;
}
```

To remove even bits, amend above code by adding a `x >>= 1` or simply

```
uint16_t IK_RemoveEvenBits(uint32_t x) {
  return IK_RemoveOddBits(x >> 1);
}
```

Tip:  Best to use *unsigned* types when coding these shift type problems.  No need to extend the sign bit of *signed* integers.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make a new integer, initialize it to 0
2. Iterate with a for loop from 0 to half the number of bits in the original integer (non-inclusive)
3. For each run through the loop, AND the original integer with `(1 << (i * 2))`. If it's nonzero, OR the new integer with `(1 << i)`
4. Finis

EDIT: Looking at the example again, it looks like what you *actually* want is to remove all the *even* bits, not the odd ones. So for that, just AND the original integer in step 3 with `(1 << (i * 2 + 1))` instead.

EDIT 2: From your example, it appears you're working with 32-bit integers, but just to cover all bases, I'm going to add that if your integer is actually 64-bit, you should replace `1` with `1ULL` in step 3.

Answer (score 3):

The odd bits can be removed (assuming they are zeroed out) in a few [bit_permute_step](http://programming.sirrida.de/perm_fn.html#bit_permute_step)s (see below), such as this:

```
x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x22222222, 1);  // Bit index swap 0,1
x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x0c0c0c0c, 2);  // Bit index swap 1,2
x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x00f000f0, 4);  // Bit index swap 2,3
x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x0000ff00, 8);  // Bit index swap 3,4
```

(generated by [calcperm](http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php))

This can easily be extended to 64bits by widening the constants and adding an extra step. If you want to remove the even bits you can just shift right by 1 first.

The definition of `bit_permute_step` is

```
t_bits bit_permute_step(t_bits x, t_bits m, t_uint shift) {
  t_bits t;
  t = ((x >> shift) ^ x) & m;
  x = (x ^ t) ^ (t << shift);
  return x;
}
```

With suitable types used.

For modern Intel processors (and Ryzen, but it is slow there) a more built-in solution is using [_pext_u32](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/683651) with a mask of all the bits you want to keep.