# Efficient bitmask enumeration in C

Tags: c, bitmask

Say I have some bitmask, such as `int b=0b1010110`.
Having another `int m`, there are 2^4=16 options on what `m & b` can be: the values of bits 1,2,4,6 of `m & b` can be all either `0` or `1` while all other values are `0`.

I want to extract an integer between `0` and `15` from `m & b` as efficiently as possible, thereby discarding all the 0-bits in `b`.

It is easy to do in `O(B)` time (where `b` has `B` bits set) by just checking the specific bits of `m`.
I want this to work independently of `b`, so no hard-coding of the bits of `b`. The bits of `b` are also available in an array.

Is there a bit-operation to do this faster, in `O(1)` or `O(log B)` or so?

Comment: Technically, since there is an upper bound on the bits to look at (32, 64, 128), your O(B) operations are actually O(1). Also, bitwise operations with no branching are *fast*.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750844/how-can-i-shuffle-bits-efficiently

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the problem at first when suggested LUT. Still possible though, but not as trivial or beneficial over the "naive" approach..

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your `m & b` is misleading. You want to only take the bits of `m` which correspond to `1`'s in `b` and "concatenate" them into a 4-bit number. The `&` operation here is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: I suggest to add some naive source code to the question to show what exactly you want. Did you check that the code generated by a compiler with optimization enabled is not efficient? Is there a guarantee that `b` contains exactly 4 1-bits? What do you want to do with the result? Do you really need it to be in range 0..15?

Comment: I think you may be looking for the pext instruction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_Bit_manipulation_instruction_set

Comment: On Intel there may be specialized instructions for this: probably [pext](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext) as mentioned above? [Some bonus insanity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932240/avx2-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-left-based-on-a-mask)

Comment: *The bits of b are also available in an array.* - can it be an array of set bit indices instead? Someone made this arrays somehow, so why not make it differently?

Comment: @return true, Curious, why work with `int` and not `unsigned` for bit manipulation code?

Comment: Thank you, it seems pext is what I was looking for!