Bit packing of groups of n repeated bits in a 32-bit word, compact to 1 bit per group
I have an unsigned 32-bit integer value that contains multiple groups of bits. All bits within one group are always the same.  Each group has the same size n (from 1 to 32 and is unknown at compile time). There are no gaps between the groups.
I need to convert each group of these bits into one bit. Next, I need to pack these bits as depicted below:

I have come up with the following C function that iterates over these bits and packs them for an arbitrary n between 1 and 32.
uint32_t PackBits(uint32_t value, uint8_t n)
{
    if (n<2) return value;

    uint32_t res = 0;
    uint32_t mask = 1;  // Also works for: mask= 1 << n-1; mask= 1 << n-2; mask= 1 << n-3; ... ; mask= 1 << n-n; 
    uint8_t s =  0;

    do {        
        res |= (value & mask) >> s;
        mask <<= n;
        s += n-1;
    } while (mask);

    return res;
}

Q: Is there a way to accomplish this goal in C without looping over these bits, with some clever sequence of multiplications, De Bruijn1, carryless, additions, xor, negations, etc... ?
For example, by taking advantage of the following bit-gathering property of multiplication, where a,b,c,d denote the least significant bits of each input byte:
   byte 3  byte 2  byte 1  byte 0
  ├──────┤├──────┤├──────┤├──────┤
  0000000d0000000c0000000b0000000a  (variable least-significant bits)
× 00001000000001000000001000000001  (constant multiplier 0x08040201 for n==8)
  ────────────────────────────────
= 0000abcd00000abc000000ab0000000a  (the product modulo 2^32)

Similar bit-gathering operations can be made with different constant multipliers for n between 6 and 31.
Maybe a similar bit-gathering operations can be made with division, too.

Footnote 1: De Bruijn sequences as perfect hash functions:
For n==2, the operation (value*0x2AAB & 0x7FFF8000) >> 15 generates a UNIQUE 16-bit number which could index a 64K element LUT, or have something done to map it to the desired bits.  64K of uint16_ts would fit in L2 cache on modern CPUs, but would only be reasonable if we were doing this for a lot of values in a row so it would pay for the demand misses to get data into L2 / L1d cache in the first place, and pay for the later cache misses from stuff that wouldn't have been evicted by other strategies that run more instructions but avoid a LUT.
For n==3, (value*0x40024B7 & 0x0FFC0000) >> 18 generates a UNIQUE 10-bit value (which can index a 1024 element LUT).
For n==4, (value*0x22AAF & 0x1FE00000) >> 21 generates a UNIQUE 8-bit value (which can index a 256 element LUT). A 256 element LUT is actually reasonable, especially since its entries are only uint8_t in size.
For n==5, (value*0x84ADF & 0x03F00000) >> 20 generates a UNIQUE 6-bit value (which can index a 64 element LUT). A 64 element LUT is actually reasonable, especially since its entries are only uint8_t in size.
(These numbers haven't been checked carefully for uniqueness)

Are you worried about performance?

Yes, I am worried about performance.

Manually, you could create custom versions of PackBits() for each possible value of n, which in turn would allow you to unroll the loop in each case. I don't know if there's a way to persuade the compiler to do all that for you automatically.

Have you measured the performance of this specific function? Did you find it uses more than ... let's say 1% of total running time?

I know that x86-64 CPUs sometimes have this wonderful instruction pext that does this operation, but I cannot rely on this instruction being available. ...nor how to coax the compiler into taking the advantage of it.

Perhaps relevant: premature optimization In any case, the input format seems to be a bit awkward, could you just use the packed bit version from the start, thus eliminating the need for this function alltogether?

@pmg:  Yes, it is for graphics purposes. The bitmaps are huge.

There are fairly efficient pext fallback functions available here https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Fast-Bithacks/blob/main/pdep_pext_u32.c.

@infinitezero: The function that generates the value does not perform bit iteration. See: https://pastebin.com/raw/50VBH8Cn Part of the Mask that this function returns is the value that the PackBits() takes as an argument.

Do you have to worry about malformed values — recognizing and diagnosing 0B10101 in an N=5 segment (which should be either 0B11111 or 0B00000)?

@JonathanLeffler: I don't have to worry. I can trust that the values are not malformed and ALL bits in each group are the same.  This means that you can test only one bit in a group.

@GeorgeRobinson Why uint32_t for res? (uint16_t and unsigned woudl work fine.)  Why uint8_t s and uint8_t s and not simply unsigned s?

@chux: uint16_t would be sufficient to contain the result for n==2 but I wanted to leave the door open for n==1.   The shift cannot be farther than 31 bits so uint5_t would've been sufficient for it, ...if it existed.

@GeorgeRobinson just use separate code paths like how we've always do for high performance code. On CPUs with BMI2 then PEXT will be used. Practically you won't see any CPU without BMI2 thought, as it's been there since 2013. And even on such ancient platforms you can always use GPU, SIMD, or parallelization to accelerate the operation

If n is unknown at compile time, you will need some conditional execution, because bit shifts larger than the machine word type are UB, so you cannot rely on a zero result.

I recommend looking at the answers to my earlier similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154745/efficient-way-to-or-adjacent-bits-in-64-bit-integer

earlier SO Q&A linked from within that github page mentioned above: What is a fast fallback algorithm which emulates PDEP and PEXT in software?. (And Peter Cordes's comment there links to a couple more)

If you're concerned about PEXT, will it at least be run on a CPU with a barrel shifter? Without one, >> and << turn into loops of a shift of one bit per iteration, AFAIK.

It looks like there are two major cases: n<6 (more groups than bits per group) and n>=6 (more bits than groups). For instance, for n=8 it's trivial. ((x&01010101U)*0x8040201)>>24 and you're done. Similar constants (every N'th bit for the mask, every N+1th bit for the multiplier) work as long as the multiplication doesn't overflow into the next group.

Are you sure the looping is slower than the branching required for every possible value of n? Is the value of n constant at runtime, so you could have a function for each possible value?

@phuclv: Pentium/Celeron branded processors before Ice Lake don't decode VEX prefixes, so BMI1/2 are gone along with AVX+FMA.  Thanks to Intel's polluting the waters, there are CPUs much more recent than 2013 without BMI2 pext, like 2020 maybe?  Also, before Gracemont, Tremont and earlier low-power Intel lacked BMI/BMI2 along with AVX. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremont_(microarchitecture)). Also, pext/pdep are very slow on AMD before Zen 2, with a huge (like 50 to 80) data-dependent number of uops.

Your looping reference implementation grabs the low bit of the "padding" above the highest full group.  Does that mean we can assume it's actually zero, unlike what you show in your diagram?  Or is that a bug?  If so, it could be fixed by starting with mask = 1uL<<(n-1); to start with the highest bit of the group, so the bit will get shifted out the top instead of into a partial group.  https://godbolt.org/z/1v8dEcf3v does that and peels the first iteration (to speed it up a bit when used in a test harness for random inputs for every n.)

Grabbing bits of the padding is definitely a bug.  I think the padding bits could be zero in my particular case but I need to verify this.

As a continuation of 4386427's answer, here's a fully-worked code generator:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const unsigned min = 2;
    const unsigned max = 16;

    puts("#include <assert.h>\n"
         "#include <stdint.h>\n");
    for (unsigned i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
        printf("static uint32_t b%d(uint32_t v)\n{\n    return v & 1", i);
        uint32_t mask = 0x1;
        for (unsigned shift = 1;  shift * i <= 32 - i;  ++shift) {
            printf("\n         | (v >> %2d) & %#06" PRIx32,
                   shift * (i-1),   mask <<= 1);
        }

        puts(";\n}\n");
    }
    puts("uint32_t PackBits(uint32_t value, uint8_t n)\n"
         "{\n"
         "    switch(n) {\n"
         "    case 1: return value;");
    for (unsigned i = min;  i <= max;  ++i) {
        printf("    case %u: return b%u(value);\n", i, i);
    }
    for (unsigned i = 17;  i <= 32;  ++i) {
        printf("    case %u: return value & 1;\n", i, i);
    }
    puts("    }\n"
         "    assert(0);\n"
         "    return 0;\n"
         "}");
}


If we call this generate-bitpack.c, then we can use it from our Makefile:
bitpack.c: generate-bitpack
    ./$< >$@

main: bitpack.o

Then this simple main.c works:
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t PackBits(uint32_t value, uint8_t n);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%#04" PRIx32 "\n",
           PackBits(0xff00f00f, 4));
}

and produces the expected output:
0xc9

For interest, here's the generated source file:
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t b2(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  1) & 0x0002
         | (v >>  2) & 0x0004
         | (v >>  3) & 0x0008
         | (v >>  4) & 0x0010
         | (v >>  5) & 0x0020
         | (v >>  6) & 0x0040
         | (v >>  7) & 0x0080
         | (v >>  8) & 0x0100
         | (v >>  9) & 0x0200
         | (v >> 10) & 0x0400
         | (v >> 11) & 0x0800
         | (v >> 12) & 0x1000
         | (v >> 13) & 0x2000
         | (v >> 14) & 0x4000
         | (v >> 15) & 0x8000;
}

static uint32_t b3(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  2) & 0x0002
         | (v >>  4) & 0x0004
         | (v >>  6) & 0x0008
         | (v >>  8) & 0x0010
         | (v >> 10) & 0x0020
         | (v >> 12) & 0x0040
         | (v >> 14) & 0x0080
         | (v >> 16) & 0x0100
         | (v >> 18) & 0x0200;
}

static uint32_t b4(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  3) & 0x0002
         | (v >>  6) & 0x0004
         | (v >>  9) & 0x0008
         | (v >> 12) & 0x0010
         | (v >> 15) & 0x0020
         | (v >> 18) & 0x0040
         | (v >> 21) & 0x0080;
}

static uint32_t b5(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  4) & 0x0002
         | (v >>  8) & 0x0004
         | (v >> 12) & 0x0008
         | (v >> 16) & 0x0010
         | (v >> 20) & 0x0020;
}

static uint32_t b6(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  5) & 0x0002
         | (v >> 10) & 0x0004
         | (v >> 15) & 0x0008
         | (v >> 20) & 0x0010;
}

static uint32_t b7(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  6) & 0x0002
         | (v >> 12) & 0x0004
         | (v >> 18) & 0x0008;
}

static uint32_t b8(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  7) & 0x0002
         | (v >> 14) & 0x0004
         | (v >> 21) & 0x0008;
}

static uint32_t b9(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  8) & 0x0002
         | (v >> 16) & 0x0004;
}

static uint32_t b10(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >>  9) & 0x0002
         | (v >> 18) & 0x0004;
}

static uint32_t b11(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >> 10) & 0x0002;
}

static uint32_t b12(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >> 11) & 0x0002;
}

static uint32_t b13(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >> 12) & 0x0002;
}

static uint32_t b14(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >> 13) & 0x0002;
}

static uint32_t b15(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >> 14) & 0x0002;
}

static uint32_t b16(uint32_t v)
{
    return v & 1
         | (v >> 15) & 0x0002;
}

uint32_t PackBits(uint32_t value, uint8_t n)
{
    switch(n) {
    case 1: return value;
    case 2: return b2(value);
    case 3: return b3(value);
    case 4: return b4(value);
    case 5: return b5(value);
    case 6: return b6(value);
    case 7: return b7(value);
    case 8: return b8(value);
    case 9: return b9(value);
    case 10: return b10(value);
    case 11: return b11(value);
    case 12: return b12(value);
    case 13: return b13(value);
    case 14: return b14(value);
    case 15: return b15(value);
    case 16: return b16(value);
    case 17: return value & 1;
    case 18: return value & 1;
    case 19: return value & 1;
    case 20: return value & 1;
    case 21: return value & 1;
    case 22: return value & 1;
    case 23: return value & 1;
    case 24: return value & 1;
    case 25: return value & 1;
    case 26: return value & 1;
    case 27: return value & 1;
    case 28: return value & 1;
    case 29: return value & 1;
    case 30: return value & 1;
    case 31: return value & 1;
    case 32: return value & 1;
    }
    assert(0);
    return 0;
}


Thanks for the improved code generator.  I am still waiting on MSalters to see if he can get his method to work for all n.

On Skylake without BMI2, this is only barely faster than the looping implementation in the question (slightly modified by peeling the first iteration).  And there's room for optimization of the loop to reduce the amount of variable-count shifts (3 uops on Intel P-cores without BMI2, unlike AMD).  https://godbolt.org/z/WzGfzdr81 Tested with GCC -O3 as the reference implementation for testing my (much faster) versions, with equal iterations for each n = 1..32, repeating the same n 10240000 times so the indirect branch in the switch predicts nearly perfectly. (0.00% branch mispredicts).

(See perf output in the comment at the bottom of my Godbolt link).  As other answers show (especially mine), it's possible to go much faster for small n with less naive implementations that combine adjacent pairs of groups.  For all n>=4 it's doable with just one AND / multiply / shift.

Making your function take a plain unsigned count avoids forcing the compiler to truncate / zero-extend it before using as an index for the jump table.  (Or unsigned long or uintptr_t would be better for that when not inlining).  It's a big function so static inline to encourage inlining when there's only one call site; GCC chooses not to even with -O3 when it's not static.

With both those things, it's about the same speed as my best looping version (PackBits_looping_bitpairs) when assigning the result to a volatile or having a DoNotOptimize asm statement force the compiler to materialize it in a register.  (Averaged over an equal number of reps for each n=1..32).  It's a bit faster than my best looping version for just n=1..16.  (5.32 G cycles vs. 6.0 G, on i7-6700k, compiled with GCC14.2 -O3 without -mbmi2 so variable-count shifts are 3 uops and need ECX).  https://godbolt.org/z/fsEqWoxvT .

So that's a lot of code size for not much speed.  And maybe no speed gain on AMD where variable-count shifts are single-uop although they still need ECX.  Or x86 with -march=x86-64-v3 (but then you should be using pext except on Zen 2 and earlier.)
(When I compare the result against my non-looping pack_n(x,n), the whole program gets faster than if I just called PackBits_looping_bitpairs. So GCC might be skipping some work for n>16 where they both just do x & 1, but that doesn't happen with yours even when it inlines. My first comment had that bias in the results.)

Probably it will be more efficient than looping as loops are not pipeline-friendly.
#define MASK(n, x) ((1U << (n + 1)) - 1) << ((x) * (n))
#define BITVAL(val, n , x) ((((val) & MASK(n,x)) == MASK(n,x))  << (x))
#define PACKBITS4(val) (BITVAL(val, 4, 0) + BITVAL(val, 4, 1) + BITVAL(val, 4, 2) + BITVAL(val, 4, 3))
#define PACKBITS5(val) (BITVAL(val, 5, 0) + BITVAL(val, 5, 1) + BITVAL(val, 5, 2))

it is for 16bits integers but you can hardcode all possible ns. When n is a constant expression it will generate code with no jumps, if not it will jump but not loop
https://godbolt.org/z/nzqYsee3Y
It can be potentially faster but it has to be tested.

Can you please add a main() function to your godbolt example with a printf() to demonstrate that the code is working? (see my answer e.g.)

n is not known at compile time, so stuff cannot be precomputed based on it.

#define MASK(n, x) ((1 << (n + 1)) - 1) << ((x) * (n)) weakness: 1 << deserves to be unsigned and may need, in general, a cast or suffix to be wide enough.

@chux indeed, great spot - was so busy counting bits and forgot about sufix/

@GeorgeRobinson you do not understand the idea, You need to provide PACKBITSx for all possible n. Then all cases will be covered.

Nice but you should give your macros on multiple lines using . It would be easier to read and understand.

You can pack 4 eight-bit and 5 six-bit fields in 3 operations using multiplication. But it will not work to pack 6 five-bit, 8 four-bit and 10 three-bit fields in the same way, since the number of packed digits exceeds the step between significant digits. Therefore, they are packed separately for even and odd digits. The packing of 16 two-bit fields is separated into 4 parts.
Functions fastpack2() and fastpack3() are improved thanks to @GeorgeRobinson's and @PeterCordes's comments, but without looking into Peter's answer.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t fastpack2(uint32_t x) {

    // ppoonnmmllkkjjiihhggffeeddccbbaa
    
    // 1. Mul
    // 000000ji00000000000000ba0-------
    // 00000000000000ba0
    // ++++++++++++++++----------------
    // 000000ji000000ba000000ba00000000

    // 2. Mul
    // 0000lk00000000000000dc00000-----
    // 000000000000dc00000
    // ++++++++++++++++----------------
    // 0000lk000000dc000000dc0000000000

    // 3. Mul
    // 00nm00000000000000fe000000000---
    // 0000000000fe000000000
    // ++++++++++++++++----------------
    // 00nm000000fe000000fe000000000000

    // 4. Mul
    // po00000000000000hg0000000000000-
    // 00000000hg0000000000000
    // +++++++++++++++++---------------
    // po000000hg000000hg00000000000000

    // 5. Or
    // 000000ji000000ba000000ba00000000
    // 0000lk000000dc000000dc0000000000
    // 00nm000000fe000000fe000000000000
    // po000000hg000000hg00000000000000
    // ++++++++++++++++----------------
    // ponmlkjihgfedcbahgfedcba00000000

    return (((x & 0b1100000000000000110) * 0b1000000010000000)
          | ((x & 0b11000000000000001100000) * 0b10000000100000)
          | ((x & 0b110000000000000011000000000) * 0b100000001000)
          | ((x & 0b1100000000000000110000000000000) * 0b1000000010)) >> 16;
}

uint32_t fastpack3(uint32_t x) {

    // 11jjjiiihhhgggfffeeedddcccbbbaaa

    // 1. Mul
    // ji0000000000fe0000000000ba00----
    // 0000fe0000000000ba00
    // 00000000ba00
    // ++++++++++----------------------
    // ji00fe00ba00fe00ba000000ba000000

    uint32_t x_even = x & 0b1100000000001100000000001100;
    x_even *= 0b100000001000000010000;

    // 2. Mul
    // 00hg0000000000dc00000000--------
    // 000000dc00000000
    // ++++++++++----------------------
    // 000000hg00dc000000dc000000000000

    uint32_t x_odd = x & 0b1100000000001100000000;
    x_odd *= 0b10000000100000000;

    // 3. Or
    // ji00fe00ba00fe00ba000000ba000000
    // 00hg00dc000000dc0000000000000000
    // ++++++++++----------------------
    // jihgfedcba00fedcba000000ba000000

    x = x_even | x_odd;
    x >>= 22;
    return x;
}

uint32_t fastpack4(uint32_t x) {

    // hhhhggggffffeeeeddddccccbbbbaaaa

    // 1. Mul
    // h0000000f0000000d0000000b0000---
    // 00f0000000d0000000b0000
    // 0000d0000000b0000
    // 000000b0000
    // ++++++++------------------------
    // h0f0d0b0f0d0b000d0b00000b0000000

    uint32_t x_odd = x & 0b10000000100000001000000010000;
    x_odd *= 0b1000001000001000001000;

    // 2. Mul
    // 0g0000000e0000000c0000000a------
    // 000e0000000c0000000a
    // 00000c0000000a
    // 0000000a
    // ++++++++------------------------
    // 0g0e0c0a0e0c0a000c0a00000a000000

    uint32_t x_even = x & 0b1000000010000000100000001;
    x_even *= 0b1000001000001000001000000;

    // 3. Or
    // h0f0d0b0f0d0b000d0b00000b0000000
    // 0g0e0c0a0e0c0a000c0a00000a000000
    // ++++++++------------------------
    // hgfedcbafedcba00dcba0000ba000000

    x = x_even | x_odd;
    x >>= 24;
    return x;
}

uint32_t fastpack5(uint32_t x) {

    // 11fffffeeeeedddddcccccbbbbbaaaaa

    // 1. Mul
    // 000000000e000000000c000000000a--
    // 0e000000000c000000000a
    // 000c000000000a
    // 00000a
    // ++++++--------------------------
    // 0e0c0a000e0c0a00000c0a0000000a00

    uint32_t x_even = x & 0b100000000010000000001;
    x_even *= 0b100000001000000010000000100;

    // 2. Mul
    // f000000000d000000000b00000------
    // 00d000000000b00000
    // 0000b00000
    // ++++++--------------------------
    // f0d0b00000d0b0000000b00000000000

    uint32_t x_odd = x & 0b10000000001000000000100000;
    x_odd *= 0b10000000100000001000000;

    // 3. Or
    // 0e0c0a000e0c0a00000c0a0000000a00
    // f0d0b00000d0b0000000b00000000000
    // ++++++--------------------------
    // fedcba000edcba00000cba0000000a00

    x = x_even | x_odd;
    x >>= 26;
    return x;
}

uint32_t fastpack6(uint32_t x) {

    // 11eeeeeeddddddccccccbbbbbbaaaaaa

    // 1. Mul
    // e00000d00000c00000b00000a-------
    // 0d00000c00000b00000a
    // 00c00000b00000a
    // 000b00000a
    // 0000a
    // +++++---------------------------
    // edcba0dcba00cba000ba0000a0000000

    x &= 0b1000001000001000001000001;
    x *= 0b1000010000100001000010000000;
    x >>= 27;
    return x;
}

uint32_t fastpack8(uint32_t x) {

    // ddddddddccccccccbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa

    // 1. Mul
    // d0000000c0000000b0000000a-------
    // 0c0000000b0000000a
    // 00b0000000a
    // 000a
    // ++++----------------------------
    // dcba0000cba00000ba000000a0000000

    x &= 0b1000000010000000100000001;
    x *= 0b10000001000000100000010000000;
    x >>= 28;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    uint32_t x;

    printf("pack2 in 12 operations:\n");
    x = 0x00000003; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack2(x));
    x = 0x0000000C; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack2(x));
    x = 0x0000000F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack2(x));
    x = 0x00000030; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack2(x));
    x = 0x33333333; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack2(x));
    x = 0xCCCCCCCC; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack2(x));
    x = 0xFFFFFFFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack2(x));

    printf("\npack3 in 6 operations:\n");
    x = 0xC0000007; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack3(x));
    x = 0xC0000038; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack3(x));
    x = 0xC000003F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack3(x));
    x = 0xC00001C0; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack3(x));
    x = 0xC71C71C7; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack3(x));
    x = 0xF8E38E38; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack3(x));
    x = 0XFFFFFFFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack3(x));

    printf("\npack4 in 6 operations:\n");
    x = 0x0000000F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack4(x));
    x = 0x000000F0; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack4(x));
    x = 0x000000FF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack4(x));
    x = 0x00000F00; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack4(x));
    x = 0x0F0F0F0F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack4(x));
    x = 0xF0F0F0F0; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack4(x));
    x = 0xFFFFFFFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack4(x));

    printf("\npack5 in 6 operations:\n");
    x = 0xC000001F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack5(x));
    x = 0xC00003E0; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack5(x));
    x = 0xC00003FF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack5(x));
    x = 0xC0007C00; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack5(x));
    x = 0xC1F07C1F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack5(x));
    x = 0xFE0F83E0; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack5(x));
    x = 0xFFFFFFFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack5(x));

    printf("\npack6 in 3 operations:\n");
    x = 0xC000003F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack6(x));
    x = 0xC0000FC0; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack6(x));
    x = 0xC0000FFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack6(x));
    x = 0xC003F000; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack6(x));
    x = 0xC0FC0FC0; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack6(x));
    x = 0xFF03F03F; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack6(x));
    x = 0xFFFFFFFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack6(x));

    printf("\npack8 in 3 operations:\n");
    x = 0x000000FF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack8(x));
    x = 0x0000FF00; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack8(x));
    x = 0x0000FFFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack8(x));
    x = 0x00FF0000; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack8(x));
    x = 0x00FF00FF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack8(x));
    x = 0xFF00FF00; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack8(x));
    x = 0xFFFFFFFF; printf("%08X -> %08X\n", x, fastpack8(x));
}

Output:
pack2 in 12 operations:
00000003 -> 00000001
0000000C -> 00000002
0000000F -> 00000003
00000030 -> 00000004
33333333 -> 00005555
CCCCCCCC -> 0000AAAA
FFFFFFFF -> 0000FFFF

pack3 in 6 operations:
C0000007 -> 00000001
C0000038 -> 00000002
C000003F -> 00000003
C00001C0 -> 00000004
C71C71C7 -> 00000155
F8E38E38 -> 000002AA
FFFFFFFF -> 000003FF

pack4 in 6 operations:
0000000F -> 00000001
000000F0 -> 00000002
000000FF -> 00000003
00000F00 -> 00000004
0F0F0F0F -> 00000055
F0F0F0F0 -> 000000AA
FFFFFFFF -> 000000FF

pack5 in 6 operations:
C000001F -> 00000001
C00003E0 -> 00000002
C00003FF -> 00000003
C0007C00 -> 00000004
C1F07C1F -> 00000015
FE0F83E0 -> 0000002A
FFFFFFFF -> 0000003F

pack6 in 3 operations:
C000003F -> 00000001
C0000FC0 -> 00000002
C0000FFF -> 00000003
C003F000 -> 00000004
C0FC0FC0 -> 0000000A
FF03F03F -> 00000015
FFFFFFFF -> 0000001F

pack8 in 3 operations:
000000FF -> 00000001
0000FF00 -> 00000002
0000FFFF -> 00000003
00FF0000 -> 00000004
00FF00FF -> 00000005
FF00FF00 -> 0000000A
FFFFFFFF -> 0000000F

Godbolt

What about pack2() and pack3() ?

@GeorgeRobinson, I already made pack6() by accident, I forgot that you need pack5(). I will try to implement pack2() and pack3() as soon as possible.

Maybe for n==2 you could mask the pairs of adjacent bits with x &= 0b01101101101101101101101101101101; and combine them with x |= x<<2;

The x &= 0xFF; at the end of fastpack4 is redundant with casting to (uint8_t).  You might want to return uint32_t instead of uint8_t so the caller knows the result is already zero-extended to 32-bit, if you're going to count that AND as a 7th operation.  (Although for some callers it's helpful for the compiler to know the value-range is small; in C there's no good way to tell the compiler that a value is small but zero-extended to a wider type, other than having the function inline so the compiler can see the final & operation.)

Anyway, nice, I'd wondered about odd/even being possible for n too small for a single multiplier like I commented on MSalters' answer, but didn't get around to trying it out.  Cool to see it's viable for 4 and 5.  Can pack3() be done with odd/even pack6()?

@PeterCordes, thanks for the note, now there is one less operation.

(uint8_t) is an operation, or at least a uint8_t return type forces the caller to extend it if you want a 32-bit integer (like you're using for printf).  Some calling conventions (including x86 ones) allow returning narrow types with garbage higher in the register, outside the actual return value.  Replacing the narrower masks with just &0xFF or (uint8_t) can let it optimize away in cases where you're storing the result to memory, for example, since the high garbage is outside the low 8 bits for pack4, 5, and 8.  And pack5 just needs the shift to clear high garbage.

https://godbolt.org/z/sMKr8ddzY shows versions that return uint32_t with &0xff masking (to let the compiler use movzx r32, r8 instead of an actual AND instruction).  Unfortunately compilers are dumb and movzx eax, al within the same register so it can't just use mov-elimination for zero latency.  Returning uint32_t lets the caller know the value is already zero-extended, so if it wants to use the whole 32-bit integer for something (like passing to printf) it can.  After inlining, it also knows its zero-extended to 64-bit so could be an array index or whatever.

I just posted an answer with a 6-operation pack3 and an 8-operation pack2.  It might be possible to avoid splitting into 2 multiplies for pack4 and/or pack5 using the same technique I used for pack3; I haven't looked at those.  (But what I'm doing is effectively two serial multiplies, the first one with a simple constant that only has 2 bits set, and one of them being the lowest, so it can be expressed as x += x<<4; in the n=3 case, after masking to get pairs of bits already adjacent.)

@PeterCordes, great job! I was thinking about how to make it an advantage that all bits of the bit fields are set to either 1 or 0, but then I lost sight of it.

@KonstantinMakarov.  Thanks for the fastpack2() and fastpack3().  I am not accepting any answers yet because I discovered that certain operations like value*0x40024B7 >> 18 & 0x0FFC0000 generate HALF of the bits in the correct positions for n==3.  I need to investigate it further.  Maybe AND masking the value before the multiplication, would shuffle the bits into the correct positions.

I finished updating my answer; starting with bit-pairs allows a LUT for n>=4 (and a single shift + mask for n>=11), and allows pack2 and pack3 with better throughput than your slicing idea.  Also, if you adjust your multipliers to bake in an extra left shift, you can put the desired bits at the top, where right-shift will zero-extend them without needing an extra &0xFF.

@PeterCordes, I will be happy to study your answer. And I improved my answer thanks to your comments.

(Partial answer; case n < √(input bits) (i.e. n<6) not fully handled yet.  For n=6 and higher, this is much faster than anything that has to shift and OR each bit separately, so is worth using for the cases where it does work even if you have to use a slower strategy for smaller n with many short bitfields.)

There are two parts to this answer: stripping redundant bits and shifting the bits.
To strip the unnecessary bits, we simply use a &mask to leave only one bit. The masks we need are ...0101010101..., ...001001001 etc. (LSB and every n'th higher bit). I.e. we need a mask[31] to cover n=2 to n=32. O(1) lookup.
Our masked number now looks like 000a000b000c instead of aaaabbbbcccc, with n-1 zeroes between the variable bits. The goal is now to get rid of those n-1 zeroes and leave abc.
For this we use multiplication. This works because multiplying by 2ᴺ is a left shift by N bits, but overflows are dropped (shifted out to the left)  because we're working modulo 2³² (uint32_t). Our number has the form 000a000b000c so that's basically sum(x[i]<<(i*N), while the goal is sum(x[i]<<i).
To achieve this, we multiply by 1000100010001000 (ones separated by n zeroes). This will leave us with a consecutive set of abc as each of the a,b,c bits with the a bit now shifted left by n bits , the b bit by 2*n+1 bits, etc (*). We just need to shift the result back so that the last bit is again in the LSB position (per the question specification) and we're done.
(*) The actual pattern will be abcbc0c00. If you have 5 or fewer groups and thus 6 or more bits, the pattern will be abcdef and overflow. But the lower bits will then be ef000f0000 so you can isolate those and fix up the overflow. This gets complex rather quickly

Note that the multipliers for N can easily be derived from the mask of N+1 so you only need one table of constants.

@GeorgeRobinson: this technique only works for fewer larger groups.  Small n is indeed the problem.  See[How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?](How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?) .  It's a similar trick to the horizontal sum of bytes (into the top of a register) in Count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer which only works when you have few enough small-enough elements that a set bit in the multiplier isn't going to make some unwanted bits overlap the wrong way.

@GeorgeRobinson: The trick is that for each set bit in the multiplier, we get a shifted copy of the other operand.  We choose the multiplier such that the bit we kept from a group goes into position next to the bit from the previous group.  This position has to be at the top, since multiplying can only shift left, and one of the bits we want is already near the top.  We also need the carry-out from lower bits that line up to not disturb the group at the top.

There's no obvious way to make this work for smaller n.  This is much better than other options for n values where it does work, especially the smaller n values.
So I'd suggest using this strategy whenever possible, and a different one for smaller n.   Perhaps you could work piecewise and e.g. do the low 16 bits separate from the high 16 bits and combine, to work for none smaller?  Forn=2you can get pairs of bits adjacent withx &= 0b0110110keeping the low bit of one group and the high of the one below.  Andx |= x<<2;` plus more masking could make groups of 4? (@George)

@PeterCordes: Would this method benefit from a wider 64-bit multiplication ?

@GeorgeRobinson: The bits that need to land next to each other still bring with them other bits equally close, regardless of how far left-shifted they are to the top of a 32-bit or 64-bit register.  But maybe that lets us do the low 16 and the high 16 into different regions of a 64-bit result, instead of having to separate for two separate multiplies, setting up for another step of shift / OR, maybe even with another multiply?

I also wonder if there's anything we can do with masks that keep a different bit in each group (rather than lowest in every group), in which case hsum of some groups would put the bits adjacent.  Maybe gives some flexibility in separate groupings within parts of a 64-bit result.

Maybe we can handle n=3 like two n=6 problems: instead of packing high/low halves to adjacent bits, pack with gaps so there's room to OR in the other half of the groups.  But that makes each result 11 (10.66) bits wide instead of 6 (5.33), so it might not work the same way.  Or if we do pack to adjacent, is there a bithack for spacing out the bits, or interleaving bits of 6-bit integers?  Squaring with carryless multiplication does that (PCLMULQDQ on XMM regs on x86), but I'm not sure about anything simpler.  (That's all I've got for ideas for now, @GeorgeRobinson)

Yes, keeping a different bit in each group (rather than lowest one in every group) has crossed my mind, too.  I have also looked into the carryless multiplications (CLMUL) but I couldn't wrap my mind around it.  This is a fascinating subject. Thanks for looking into it.

@MSalters: When you wrote: "To achieve this, we multiply by 1000100010001000 (ones separated by n zeroes)" did you mean "To achieve this, we multiply by 10000100001000010000 (ones separated by n zeroes)" ? These are examples for n==4, correct ?

@GeorgeRobinson: I've simplified the example to just abc since spelling out 32 bits would be rather verbose. For n==4 you'd have abcdefgh which overflows without CLMUL.

@MSalters:  I don't think you're paying sufficient attention to the amount of zeros that you have when you write "(ones separated by n zeroes)"

Summary: Use x86 BMI2 pext or equivalent if available (except on AMD Zen 2 and earlier where it's very slow), with a 32-entry LUT of uint32_t masks for n=1..32
Otherwise, special case n<4 with custom functions,
n>=4 can use a LUT of a mask, multiplier, and shift count for each n.
n>=11 can use one shift and AND to keep 1 bit, or 2 that span the boundary between 2 groups
Tested version on Godbolt that handles all n.
...ddddccccbbbbaaaa masked to keep adjacent pairs like
...000dc000000ba000 gives us half as many groups to deal with vs keeping the low or high bit of each group.  A magic-multiplier LUT works down to n=4, vs. n=6 in @MSalters's answer.
Starting with bit-pairs also helps significantly for pack2 and pack3.

Full code, tested for all n with random inputs
All of this on Godbolt (and a bit more, including SSE2 / SSE4.1 versions that might be worth using for n=2, 4, and 8, and a unit test, and an AVX-512 + GFNI idea for n=2).  If you care about a specific compiler and/or CPU, there are probably some tweaks to convince a compiler to emit slightly better asm for some cases.
edit changelog: much faster test code for making all bits in a group equal, and faster looping versions.  Various tuning: dispatch to the LUT seems good for n=4..16, don't use the n=11..16 function so the switch has fewer different cases (a couple cmp/jcc instead of a jump table)
#include <stdint.h>
#define NDEBUG  // asserts are mostly for documentation about which n ranges different functions handle
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

// n=17..32 is just x&1
uint32_t pack_n_11_to_16(uint32_t x, unsigned n)
{
    assert(n>=11 && n<=16);
    x >>= n-1;
    return x & 3;
}

// unsigned long n avoids the need to zero-extend to pointer width, if it didn't inline.
static inline
uint32_t pack_LUT(uint32_t x, unsigned long n)
{
    assert(n>=4 && n<=16);  // table currently only goes up to n=16
    struct LUT {
        // group both arrays into one static variable so compilers don't waste instructions getting the base address separately for each.
        uint8_t shift[32-4];  // counts first so the offset to next array is small, fitting in a disp8
        alignas(8)
        struct {uint32_t mask, mult;} maskmult[]; // flexible array member that's as long as we want it to be.
    };
    static const struct LUT lut = {
      .maskmult = {
        {0b00011000000110000001100000011000, ((1uL<<18) | (1u<<12) | (1u<<6) | 1)<<3 }, // n=4 ; 8 groups = 4 pairs
        {0b00000011000000001100000000110000, ((1uL<<16) | (1u<<8)  | 1)<<6 },  // n=5 ; 6 groups = 3 pairs
        {0b00100000000001100000000001100000, ((1uL<<20) | (1u<<10) | 1)<<2 },  // n=6 ; 5 groups = 3ish pairs
        {0b00000000001100000000000011000000, ((1uL<<12) | 1)<<0 }, // n=7 ; 4 groups, 2 pairs // no high garbage even without shifting to the top, shift=18
        {0b00000001100000000000000110000000, ((1uL<<14) | 1)<<0 }, // n=8 ; 4 groups, 2 pairs
        {0b00000100000000000000001100000000, ((1uL<<16) | 1)<<0 }, // n=9 ; 3 groups, 2ish pairs
        {0b00100000000000000000011000000000, ((1uL<<18) | 1)<<0 }, // n=10 ; 3 groups, 2ish pairs
        {0b00000000000000000000110000000000, 1}, // n=11   one pair, don't need to multiply anymore if we want to dispatch to a third version.
        {0b00000000000000000001100000000000, 1}, // n=12
        {3<<12, 1}, // n=13
        {3<<13, 1}, // n=14
        {3<<14, 1}, // n=15
        {3<<15, 1}, // n=16
        // Use a simpler strategy for larger n to save table size, even though dispatcher has more to choose from.
      },
      .shift = {
        32-8, 32-6, 32-5,  // n = 4..6 shift from the top to clear high garbage
        18, 21, 24, 27,    // n=7..10 have a second bit-pair (or single bit) at the top
        // n=11 and up just have 2 or fewer groups, trivial shift and keep only 2 or 1 bit
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
        // could choose multipliers so these are all 30
      }
    };
    x &= lut.maskmult[n-4].mask;
    x *= lut.maskmult[n-4].mult;
    x >>= lut.shift[n-4];
    return x;
}

On Intel P-cores (i.e. Sandybridge-family), variable-count shifts are 3 uops due to having to preserve FLAGS for the count=0 case.  (https://uops.info/)  BMI2 shrx avoids that, but if we had BMI2 on an Intel CPU we'd just use pext.  Still, for a loop using the same n repeatedly, pack_n_ge_11 should be very good for large n, avoiding a multiply compared to the LUT version.
And the special cases for n=2 and n=3:
uint32_t pack2(uint32_t x)
{
        // 0po00nm00lk00ji00hg00fe00dc00ba0   AND mask to keep bit-pairs
    x &= 0b01100110011001100110011001100110;
        // 0ponm0000lkji0000hgfe0000dcba000    x += x<<2 /*LEA*/;  x &= mask;
    x += x<<2;
    x &= 0b01111000011110000111100001111000;
        // 0ponmlkji00000000hgfedcba0000000    x += x<<4;  x &= mask2;
    x += x<<4;
    x &= 0b01111111100000000111111110000000;
        // ponmlkjihgfedcba0000000000000000    x *= (1<<1) | (1<<9)
    x *= (1u<<1)|(1u<<9);
    x >>= 16;
    return x;
}

uint32_t pack3(uint32_t x) {
        // 0000j00i00h00g00f00e00d00c00b00a // incoming x
    x &= 0b00001100001100001100001100001100;
        //     ji    hg    fe    dc    ba
    x += x<<4;      // x *= 17
        // ji  jihg  hgfe  fedc  dcba  ba
    x &= 0b00001111000000001111000000001111;
        //     jihg        fedc        ba
        //         fedc        ba   // partial product from 1<<8
        // fedc        ba           // partial product from 1<<16
        // ((1<<0) | (1<<8) | (1<<16))<<4
    x *= (1<<4) | (1<<12) | (1<<20);
    // with the multiplier left-shifted by 4, result goes to the top, no high garbage after shifting
    x >>= 22;
    // x &= 0x3FF;  // 10-bit.  
    return x;
}

To dispatch to these functions according to n, I made a wrapper that you'd actually call.  Make the others static inline.  Build with profile-guided optimization if you want to hint the compiler which n values are common in your use-cases, so it favours them in the chain of compare/branch.  If you're using this in a loop, make sure it can inline.  Ideally you'd want loop unswitching, where the compiler turns this into multiple loops with branching to select one loop, instead of branching every loop iteration.  But at least the LUT loads and constant setup and so on can be hoisted.
uint32_t pack_n(uint32_t x, unsigned n)
{
#ifdef HAVE_FAST_PEXT
    return pack_pext(x, n);
#endif
    switch (n){
        default:  return x & 1; // one group for n >= 17

        case 11 ... 16: //return pack_n_11_to_16(x, n);
        case 8:  // return pack8_sse2(x);
        case 10:
        case 9:
        case 7:
        case 6:
        case 5:
        case 4:
            return pack_LUT(x, n);

        case 3:   return pack3(x);
        case 2:
#ifdef __SSE4_1__
            return pack2_sse4(x);
#else
            return pack2(x);
#endif
        case 1:   return x;  // trivial
    }
}

And to see how the masking works before I made the LUT version, I made n=4, n=5, and two n=8 versions.  (One n=8 version uses the bitpair trick, the other starts with 4 separate 1-bit groups.)  AArch64 does very well with the bitpairs pack8, avoiding having to construct a 32-bit multiplier constant.  (I'm assuming most AArch64 CPus have efficient support for orr reg, reg, reg, lsl #imm with a shifted source operand.)
// see pack5 and pack8 on Godbolt
uint32_t pack4(uint32_t x) {
        // hhhhggggffffeeeeddddccccbbbbaaaa
    x &= 0b00011000000110000001100000011000;
        // 000hg000000fe000000dc000000ba000  // result, and 1<<0 partial product
        // 00000fe000000dc000000ba000000000  // 1<<6 partial product
        // 0000000dc000000ba000000000000000  // 1<<12
        // 0dc000000ba000000000000000000000  // 1<<18
        // with an extra shift by 3 to put the result at the top, avoiding high garbage
    x *= (1uL<<21) | (1uL<<15) | (1u<<9) | (1u<<3);
    x >>= (32-8);
    return x;
}


pext - parallel bits-extract
A few ISAs like x86 with BMI2 pext/pdep have hardware support for bit pack / deposit.  If supported, this is ideal.  (Except on AMD Zen 2 and earlier where it's supported only by very slow microcode, as bad as one per 50 to 150 cycle throughput).  See also my answer on a related question, which mentions AArch64 SVE2 BITPERM on SIMD vector elements, and RISC-V extension v vcompress.vm which packs with byte granularity based on a mask.
Currently there are no portable idioms which compilers recognize and turn into pext when it's available on the target, so you can only get it via an intrinsic).
static const uint32_t extract_masks[32] = {-1uL /* n=1 */, 0x55555555uL /*n=2*/, ...};
return  _pext_u32(x, extract_masks[n-1]);

If hardware support for pext/pdep isn't available, you don't want a generic software emulation of it with a table of masks for each n, that would be slow because it's a hard operation to emulate.  (You'd be encoding the bit-positions to extract into a mask that needs decoding, instead of into instructions that actually do the operations.)
n=8 can be done on x86 with movd xmm0, edi / pmovmskb eax, xmm0 to extract the high bit of each byte into a bitmask.  (_mm_cvtsi32_si128 / _mm_movemask_epi8).  If that case is common and important for performance, could be worth considering, especially if you have an array of multiple inputs of the same n to do so you can actually use SIMD to do 4 or 8 at once (and separate the 4-bit nibbles of the result if needed.)
See pack2_sse4, pack4_sse4 and pack8_sse2 in the Godbolt link above for possibilities.  Some might be worth using for compile-time-constant n for a single x at a time, but not with extra branching to special-case the dispatching.  pmaddwd or SSSE3 pmaddubsw could also be useful for moving bits within 16 or 32-bit elements.
You mentioned graphics and huge bitmaps; decoding 2 or more inputs in parallel is very possible, especially with AVX2 for 32-byte vectors.  If that's your real problem, ask a separate question; decoding one at a time sucks; do 2 at a time with uint64_t at least for larger n.  I've mostly been assuming one-off use cases in the rest of this answer since you only asked about decoding one at once.
With AVX-512VBMI, vpmultishiftqb can get the desired bit to a byte within a 64-bit element of a vector, where you can get them into a mask.  Broadcast-load and/or shuffle to feed it if necessary.  Or with AVX512-BITALG, vpshufbitqmb goes directly to a mask instead of grabbing 8-bit groups into vectors.
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpshufbitqmb
http://0x80.pl/articles/avx512-galois-field-for-bit-shuffling.html discusses GFNI for shuffling bits within a byte, great for vectorizing small n, especially n=2, to produce a vector result.  See pack2_GFNI_AVX2 on Godbolt for a sketch of an idea.

For large-enough n (fewer wider groups), AND masking and then moving bits around with magic multiplier constants as in How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)? works very well, and can do the job in one AND/multiply/shift step for n>=4
A multiply adds multiple shifted copies of one input, according to the set bit positions in the multiplier.  If the bits you care about are few enough and far enough apart, you can avoid overlap of partial-products that could flip a bit you want to deposit directly or via carry-out from lower bits.  Or can be used to horizontally sum byte in a 32 or 64-bit integer, for example, by having all the partial products align a different byte into the top byte.
For any given multiplier that puts bits adjacent to each other, we can left-shift the multiplier to bake that left-shift into the multiply.  Placing the bits at the top lets a right shift bring them to the bottom zero-extended, with no high garbage.
The shift count is 32 - (32/n), but we use another LUT because division is expensive.  So 12 B instead of 8 per struct, or a separate uint8_t array which is probably better.  (Smaller total cache footprint for the LUT if many different ns are frequently used, and the array of mask and multiplier can then have 8-byte elements. Cheaper addr math, and can be naturally aligned so both are in one cache line, and AArch64 ldp load-pair won't split across cache lines.)
MSalters' answer suggests a way to use one lookup table and the same code for all n>=6, but apparently that bit-reverses the result?  That's fine on ARM, use rbit + and instead of a right shift, otherwise it's a problem.
@Konstantin Makarov's answer shows that we can separate into odd/even and combine at the end to extend the magic-multiplier idea to smaller n with special-case functions, but starting with bit-pairs can do better.  I used his test harness and comment style as a starting point for my versions.

Efficient pack3, about 6 operations including 1 multiply
I came up with a more efficient pack3 (above) which starts out by masking to get 5 bit-pairs, spanning the boundaries between 3-bit groups.  (The high bit of one group is next to the low bit of the next group.)  It compiles nicely:
# clang 19 -O3
pack3:
  and   edi, 204522252
  mov   eax, edi
  shl   eax, 4           # shifting EDI would have taken MOV off the critical path; Ice Lake has mov-elim disabled
  or    eax, edi         # note that clang turned + into OR, seeing that no set bits can overlap
  and   eax, 251719692
  imul  eax, eax, 1052688
  shr   eax, 22
  ret

Instruction-level parallelism is poor; this is one chain of dependent work.  But it's quite short so can overlap with surrounding code nicely.
For x86-64 as a non-inline function, this is about as efficient as possible.  x86 can multiply by 3, 5, and 9 with LEA (e.g. lea eax, [rdi + rdi*8]), but it's only a 2-bit shift count so 17 needs either an imul  eax, edi, 17 (1 uop but 3 cycle latency) or 3 instructions (including a mov) with 2 cycle latency assuming mov-elimination happens.  Compilers prefer lower latency.
x86 allows 32-bit immediates for all these instructions. AArch64 needs to materialize the 3 constants with 2 instructions each (mov + movk), because its bitwise insns can only encode repeating patterns of contiguous set bits in 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32-bit groups, not odd lengths.  Once constants are set up (e.g. hoisted out of a loop), orr  w8, w8, w8, lsl #4 to shift-and-OR in a single instruction is better than x86 can do.

n==2 with repeated shift/OR to make more bits contiguous
n=2 would be doable in log2(32/n = 16) = 4 mask/shift/OR steps just straight-forwardly closing up gaps between pairs of groups to get half as many groups that are twice as wide.
Starting with bit-pairs skips basically skips the first step, leaving only 3.  It compiles pretty efficiently for x86-64 and AArch64:
# x86-64 gcc -O3
pack2:
  and   edi, 1717986918
  lea   edx, [rdi+rdi*4]
  and   edx, 2021161080
  mov   eax, edx
  sal   eax, 4
  add   eax, edx
  and   eax, 2139127680
  imul  eax, eax, 514
  shr   eax, 16
  ret

This is 8 ALU operations, 9 uops total including the mov for x86-64.  (Also not counting ret since it inlines).  Clang makes it 9 instructions for AArch64, but avoids a multiply.
# armv8 clang -O3
pack2:
  and   w8, w0, #0x66666666   # repeating bit-patterns can be immediates
  orr   w8, w8, w8, lsl #2
  and   w8, w8, #0x78787878
  orr   w8, w8, w8, lsl #4    # x |= x<<4;
  and   w8, w8, #0x7f807f80
  lsr   w9, w8, #7           # instead of multiply, 2 shifts
  lsl   w8, w8, #1
  bfi   w8, w9, #16, #8      # to set up for bitfield-insert
  lsr   w0, w8, #16
  ret

Left shifting by 1 to start with could simplify the end to just another orr with a shifted source (x += x<<16;).  In a loop with a constant in a register, the first instruction could be and w8, w15, w0, lsl #1 on AArch64 and ARM32, but on other ISAs that shift would be part of the critical-path latency.

If pack2 had to start from 0p0o0n0m0l0k0j0i0h0g0f0e0d0c0b0a evenly-spaced bits instead of bit-pairs, x += x & 0x11111111; could left shift the odd bits, like shifting a up next to b etc. to get to the same point as with x & 0b0110....  Adding a bit to itself shifts it left by 1, but adding 0 leaves it unchanged.
But x86 can do the obvious x += x<<1; x &= mask; with LEA + AND vs. MOV / AND / ADD.

Excellent answer!  I am not accepting any answers yet because I discovered that certain operations like value*0x40024B7 >> 18 & 0x0FFC0000 generate HALF of the bits in the correct positions for n==3.  I need to investigate it further.  Maybe AND masking the value before the multiplication, would shuffle the bits into the correct positions.

You wrote: "Otherwise use @MSalters' answer for n>=6."  however his answer generates the bits in the reverse order.

@GeorgeRobinson: Starting with bit-pairs, we can do all n>=4 with AND / multiply / shift using a lookup table, putting bits in non-reversed order.  You just have to choose your multiplier to put bits where you want them.  Working on an edit, but work-in-progress code with a switch that covers all n: https://godbolt.org/z/METdPrEPT

@GeorgeRobinson: ok, updated my answer with versions that cover all n.  I haven't tested it all; if there are bugs they should be solvable without major changes, since I think the basic ideas are right, but I might have some bit-positions or shift counts wrong somewhere.

@GeorgeRobinson: In your n=5 case, you show the two padding bits being 11 at the top, above the highest full group.  If you could make those guaranteed 0, it would save some operations for the n>16 non-LUT case (pack_n_ge_11)

I highly doubt it would be practical, but theoretically possible and no loop: a lookup table.
To make it slightly more usable, we can reduce the memory needed a little.
n can go from 2 to 32, so we need 5 bits for it. The data itself is 32 bits, but the first and last one can be ignored since the smallest group is 2 bits. The output of the function is an uint32_t but we actually only need 16 bits at most.
So our biggest address possible would be 35 bit for an array of uint16_t, so we'd need 64 GB of RAM - which is not that rare in today's computers.
Edit: Actually, since we only need one bit out of two from the data, we can reduce it from 32 bits to 16 bits with some simple operations, which would reduce the table size to just 4 MB. And as the comments show, there might well be ways to reduce it even further.
We have to use another program/script to generate the look up table, but the function itself would be something like this:
uint32_t PackBits(uint32_t value, uint8_t n)
{
    const uint16_t lookupTable[] = {/* Generated numbers here */};
    n = n & 0x1F;
    uint64_t address = (value&0x7FFFFFFF) >> 1;
    address |= (uint64_t)n << 30;

    return (uint32_t)lookupTable[address];
}

Despite only requiring a few simple operations and fetching data in memory, I imagine it might be slower than other solutions because there's no way this table will go into any CPU cache.

64GB LUT - very funny ;) .  Wouldn't it be better to look up the answer in a 65kB LUT indexed by a 17-bit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence ?

@GeorgeRobinson: How do you transform the input into a 17-bit anything?  Isn't that most of the problem?  I agree that a 64GB LUT is laughable; even if you have that much RAM, random access to even the chunks of it for a single n will likely miss in cache unless you're decoding the same value repeatedly (or one that differs only in the low group).  And probably TLB miss.  And maybe even page-fault to read another page of .rodata in from disk.  Even just a cache miss all the way to DRAM is probably slower than even a fairly naive / straightforward shift/AND/OR instruction sequence.

@PeterCordes: These De Brujin sequences can act as a perfect hashing function with minimal number of operations. The output of this hashing operation can serve as a narrow and UNIQUE index the LUT that bananeeg is proposing -  albeit a ~1000000x smaller one....

@PeterCordes: For example: for n==2 the operation (value*0x2AAB & 0x7FFF8000) >> 15 generates a UNIQUE 16-bit index to a 64k element LUT ... and for n==3 the operation (value*0x125B7 & 0x0FFC0000) >> 18 generates a UNIQUE 10-bit index to a 1024 element LUT ...and for n==4 the operation (value*0x2266F & 0x1FE00000) >> 21 generates a UNIQUE 8-bit index to a 256 element LUT ...and for n==5 the operation (value*0x119DF & 0x03F00000) >> 20 generates a UNIQUE 6-bit index to a 64 element LUT.

@GeorgeRobinson: Oh cool.  You should add that to the question.  PS: on most ISAs, masking after shifting (with an unsigned right shift) is more efficient since small masks can sometimes fit as an immediate.  e.g. RISC-V has andi reg, reg, imm12 with a 12-bit sign-extended immediate.  x86 allows small-enough immediates to be only imm8 instead of imm32, saving code-size.  AArch64 allows any contiguous range of set bits anywhere in a 64-bit integer as an immediate (or repeating pattern of same like 0x7777... for any power-of-2 repeat width), so on AArch64 it doesn't matter if you mask first.

@PeterCordes:  You are welcome to add this info to my question, but first check if these operations really generate UNIQUE indexes, because I have calculated these constants manually with the Windows calculator and I'm going to sleep now.

I'm not familiar with those De Bruijn sequences, but if someone can make it work that would be interesting. Also, I edited my answer because I made an oversight; since we only need one bit out of two of the data, we can easily reduce down to 16 bits (rather than just 30) and thus get a table of 4 MB.

@bananeeg: The De Bruijn sequences are listed at the bottom of the original question now.  Take a look at them to compress the indices to your LUT.
